# Erro ao abrir um jar na linha de comandos

Tags: java

Tenho o seguinte código e estou a usar uma biblioteca para listar os campos do cartão do cidadão.

Quanto tento correr no DOS não funciona.

```
import java.io.*;
import pteidlib.*;
public class main {

        public String nome;
        public String data;
        public String pais;
        public String sexo;


        static
          {
            try
            {

                System.loadLibrary("pteidlibj");


            }
            catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
            {
              System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
              System.exit(1);
            }
          }


        public void PrintIDData(PTEID_ID idData) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException
          {
                nome = idData.firstname + " " + idData.name ;
                data =  idData.birthDate;
                pais = idData.country;
                sexo = idData.sex;
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");

           writer.println(nome);   
            writer.println(data);
            writer.close();
                System.out.print(nome);
          }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException, PteidException{
              main  test = new main();

           pteid.Init("");
      //test.TestChangeAddress();
        // Don't check the integrity of the ID, address and photo (!)
      pteid.SetSODChecking(false);

      int cardtype = pteid.GetCardType();
      switch (cardtype)
      {
          case pteid.CARD_TYPE_IAS07:
              System.out.println("IAS 0.7 card\n");
              break;
          case pteid.CARD_TYPE_IAS101:
              System.out.println("IAS 1.0.1 card\n");
              break;
          case pteid.CARD_TYPE_ERR:
              System.out.println("Unable to get the card type\n");
              break;
          default:
              System.out.println("Unknown card type\n");
      }

      // Read ID Data
      PTEID_ID idData = pteid.GetID();
      if (null != idData)
      {
        test.PrintIDData(idData);
      }


}
}
```

Preciso de correr isto na linha de comandos `java -cp test.jar main` para depois ser chamado na linha de comandos dá-me este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pra executar um jar por linha de comando é    java -jar seujar.jar     .

Comment: E qual é o caminho relativo da sua biblioteca externa?

Comment: o meu caminho da bilbioteca externa esta no C:\

Comment: @user2964140 não fiz um teste aqui, mas acredito que se você fizer `java -jar test.jar -cp .;c:\ ` funcionará

Comment: da-me este erro no main manifest attribute,in test.jar

Comment: posso pegar no jar gerado pelo meu codigo e coloca-lo no c:\  ?

Comment: testem ai ...só imprime se tiverem um cartao do cidadão

Comment: não funciona com esse comando...

Answer (score 2):

Acrescentando à resposta de @user2964140, e assumindo que a biblioteca está no c:\ como você falou, o comando pra executar deve ser:

```
java -cp .;c:\suabiblioteca.jar -jar test.jar
```

Essa resposta assume que o seu jar test.jar foi feito corretamente (isto é, inclui um MANIFEST.MF com o header que fala qual a classe que contém o seu método `public static void main(String args[])`.
Se não for o caso, é aconselhável ler os tutoriais da Oracle sobre como criar jars e sobre manifest files.

Uma última sugestão é incluir a sua biblioteca no diretório `lib/` dentro do seu jar, para que sua aplicação contenha tudo o que precisa.